# Creating an empty directory (NSIS)

Tags: windows, installation, nsis, error-checking, create-directory

How can I do it by NSIS 2.46?

I know this is probably a dumb question, but how the heck do I create an empty directory and check for errors?

I do so:

```
ClearErrors
CreateDirectory $R1
${If} ${Errors} 
  DetailPrint "failed"
  MessageBox mb_IconStop|mb_TopMost|mb_SetForeground "Can not create folder $R1"
  Abort
${Else}
  DetailPrint "done"
${EndIf}
```

if the variable $R1 is

- "c:\test" - done
- "c:\con" - failed ("con" - reserved on Windows)
- "qwer:\test2" - done
- "qwer\test3" - done (without ":")

why "test2" and "test3" without errors?

**UPDATE:**
How to make that it was an error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I decided:

```
ClearErrors
CreateDirectory $R1
${If} ${Errors} 
${OrIfNot} ${FileExists} "$R1\*.*"
  DetailPrint "failed"
  MessageBox mb_IconStop|mb_TopMost|mb_SetForeground "Can not create folder $R1"
  Abort
${Else}
  DetailPrint "done"
${EndIf}
```

have more ideas?

Answer (score 6):

In order to check for errors you should check the error flag, which you're doing right. I think the problem is you should use quotes:

```
CreateDirectory "$R1"
```

Answer (score 3):

NSIS does some unfortunate (IMHO) path mangling and only accepts `:` as the 2nd character, otherwise it is silently stripped. This means that `"qwer\test2"` and `"qwer:\test2"` are treated the same at run-time. You can verify this by copying it to one of the special path registers:

```
!macro TestNsisPathMangling p
Push $InstDir
StrCpy $InstDir "${p}"
DetailPrint "Old=${p}"
DetailPrint "New=$InstDir"
Pop $InstDir
!macroend

!insertmacro TestNsisPathMangling "qwer\test2"
!insertmacro TestNsisPathMangling "qwer:\test2"
```

This leaves us with `"qwer\test2"` and this is a relative path and those are officially [not supported](http://anders_k.users.sourceforge.net/public/NSIS/2.46/Manual.html#createdirectory) when calling CreateDirectory. If you try this in NSIS 3 you should get:

> CreateDirectory: Relative paths not supported

**Edit:**

If the path is entered by the user you can call the Windows function `GetFullPathName` to get a absolute/full path:

```
Push "qwer\test3"
System::Call 'KERNEL32::GetFullPathName(ts,i${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN},t.r1,t)i.r0'
${If} $0 <> 0
    DetailPrint "GetFullPathName=$1"
${Else}
    DetailPrint "GetFullPathName failed"
${EndIf}
```

Comment: @AndreiKrasutski What does that mean? Just use a full path and you should be OK.

Comment: Variable $R1 sets the user in Page Custom, so it can set a bad directory, but I have to check.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for `CreateDirectory`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Reference/CreateDirectory) -- rather irresponsibly -- plainly says `error flag is set` leaving ambiguity to an occasional NSIS scripter as to what this means.

To no surprise, error handling in NSIS is documented [very sparsely](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/mediawiki/index.php?title=Reference/IfErrors) as well... but fortunately they do explain how to catch errors if you read the comments thoroughly.

> if it is set, it will goto `[first param]`, otherwise it will goto `[second param]`

Take special note of the word `goto` in the docs which is a throwback to GOTO **line jumping**.

```
ClearErrors
CreateDirectory $R1
IfErrors 0 +2
Call ErrorHandler
```

What's not immediately obvious is that `+2` **JUMPS OVER** the error handler.  And now one can deduce that `0` will goto the **NEXT LINE** -- the error handler.

The above example should properly handle an error, given that `:ErrorHandler` is defined somewhere in your script, which can be replaced with any logic you like.

I recommended `; Commenting heavily` as this scripting language can be difficult to read if you don't work with it daily.